# Monotouch iphone - hide keyboard when click clear (x)

Tags: .net, iphone, xamarin.ios

My question relates to using monotouch for iphone development.

My layout is very simple, its a toolbar, with a textbox in it.
I have enabled the clear button option on the textbox.

I've put some code together as follows were every key-press calls my delegate therefore if the user clears all the chars in the textbox the iphone keyboard disappears.

However if the user chooses the clear (x) button on the textbox the delegate is still raised ( I have checked this ) but the ResignFirstResponder doesn't hide the keyboard.

```
txtReply.EditingChanged  += delegate {
                    if ( txtReply.Text == "" ) {
                        txtReply.ResignFirstResponder();
                    }
        };
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Replace:
    ( txtReply.Text == "" )

With this:
    (txtReply.Text == nil || [txtReply.text length] == 0)

Comment: hi - this didnt work. The code is actually hitting the txtReply.ResignFirstResponder() line - its just not hiding the keyboard. txtReply.Text = "" when I click clear (x).

Answer (score 0):

You need to subclass the UITextFieldDelegate and override the ShouldClear method. The UITextField calls this method when the built-in clear button is hit. The subclassing will look like [this](http://monotouch.pastebin.com/DAX4mCd5). In the overrode method, which is passed the text field, that you can check to see if the text is blank and if so dismiss the keyboard.

Comment: Hi @Kevin-McMahon, Strange I was thinking that this should work.  The method gets hit but doesn't work.  here is my code: [Link](http://monotouch.pastebin.com/006vrnDT)  I guess I should mention that my textbox is contained within a **bold**UIToolbar.